# Parse file with multiples values lines C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have to parse a file that is constructed like this :

```
User: jcruz Name: Jules Last: Cruz  Email: Some@email.com 
User: jdoe Name: John Last: Doe Email: Some@email.com 
User: pmartin Name: Pete Last: Martin Email: Some@email.com 
User: rrichard Name: Reed Last: Richard Email: Some@email.com
```

I need to split every line taking just Name, Last Name and Email into an object of the type

```
var contact = new Conctact {
    Name = fieldFromLine,
    Last= fieldFromLine,
    Email = fieldFromLine
}
```

So my problem is which tool use : `String.Split` or `Regex.Split`. and how to implement it.

Thank you very much...

This is what a Have done so far:

```
String archivo = ((FileDialog)sender).FileName;

        using (TextReader sr = new StreamReader(archivo,Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            String line = String.Empty;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null )
            {
                string[] result = Regex.Split(line,"User:");
                //How to get the other fields...


            }

        }
```

Comment: You could use either; both are equally capable of helping you solve this problem.  What have you actually tried with respect to either solution?  What is preventing you from using either one to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you do that while reading the file token by token?

Comment: Use Regex. Update the question if you have a more specific problem.

Comment: **Which tool to use?**: use Regex coz the values of each field is of variable length. hence easier to use Regex. (not that you cannot accomplish by string.Split) **How to implement it?**: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Kash - variable length is not an issue, `string.Split()` deals with that just fine as well. And "What have you tried?" is silly here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - never said it would be an issue with string.Split(), its just easier with a Regex. I am kapish with the question of which one to use, but the question about how to implement it should not be encouraged especially if you aware about both classes. Silliness is relative.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The question does have a slight "send me teh codez" quality, but I think that's unintentional.

Comment: Sorry for that, my fault, I am really tried with String.Split, but I am a litle dark about the use with multiples occurrences. I am not intended to get the code, and I am do not know a lot about regex, if anything.  My appologies for my Silliness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result =File.ReadLines(fileName)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new string[]{"User:", "Name:", "Last:", "Email:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(parts => new Conctact(){ Name = parts[1], Last = parts[2], Email = parts[3] })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Oooh, I'll have to try this :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public class  contact 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Lname { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
List<contact> contact = new List<contact>();
        private void split()
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"txt file address");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
               var splitline=line.Split(':');
           string name = splitline[2].Replace("Last", "");
           string lname = splitline[3].Replace("Email","");
           contact.Add(new contact { Name = name, Lname = lname, Email = splitline[4] });
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will break on names that contain spaces.

Comment: The revised version will break if their first name begins with `Last`.

Comment: so @ L.B answer is the best for you:D

Answer (score 0):

Regex is overkill. Also note that some last names that contain spaces.

```
Contact c = new Contact();
string () tokens = input.Split(":".ToCharArray());

if (tokens.Count < 5)
    return; // error

// now strip the last word from each token
c.Name = tokens(2).Substring(0, tokens(2).LastIndexOf(" ".ToCharArray())).Trim();
c.Last = tokens(3).Substring(0, tokens(3).LastIndexOf(" ".ToCharArray())).Trim();
c.Email = tokens(4).Trim();
```

Comment: Your solution is brittle and breaks if a name contains a space.

Comment: @David : `FindLastOf()` will stop at the space before the keyword. No?

Comment: @egrunin Pretty sure you meant to use `LastIndexOf`.  There is no `FindLastOf` unless you write your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: neither.

Use a simple finite-state machine parser to read the file because **unless you can guarantee that the text values will never be "Name:" or "Last:" or "Email:"** then you'll run into problems with string splitting. Also FSM-based parsers are significantly faster than string splitting (as there is no extraneous string allocation).

I don't have the time to write out an entire parser, but here's the simple logic:

```
enum State { InUser, InName, InLast, InEmail }

State currentState = State.InUser; // you start off with the 'cursor' in the "User" section
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // this holds the current string element
foreach(Char c in entireTextFile) { // presumably using `StreamReader.Read()`
    switch( currentState ) {
        case InUser:
             switch( c ) {
                 // state transition logic here
             }
             // append the character to the StringBuilder until you've identified and reached the next field, then save the sb value to the appropriat
        case InName:
             // and so on...
    }
}
```

Of course, an FSM parser is fundamentally the same thing as a Regular Expression parser, but it means you get to code the state-transitions yourself rather than using RegEx's syntax which is faster, performance-wise.

If your project is small and don't care about performance, and can guarantee certain data formatting rules then I'd go with regex.

But never, ever, use String.Split to read a file.

Comment: I think you can guarantee (safely assume) none of the data will contain a `:`. And writing your own FSM is serious overkill.

Comment: `But never, ever, use String.Split to read a file.` That's just bad advice.  It depends entirely on the contents of the file, and the rules for generating it.  If you have a simple delimiter, and you can be sure that there are no escaped (or unescaped) delimiters inside of a particular field then it's a perfectly acceptable option.  While it may not be desirable here, saying "never" is certainly not correct.

Comment: In a file this simple it's easy (as well as necessary) to do sanity checking on each line and toss the invalid lines.

Comment: @egrunin As I said, I probably wouldn't use `Split` here.  I would however use it on a comma, tab, or pipe delimited file if I could be sure that there are no delimiters within fields.  (It is frequently possible to add that constraint when you have control over the generation of the files.)  For parsing a tab delimited file having that constraint `string.Split` won't ever break.